# Access 97 custom function

Tags: ms-access

I need to write a custom function that will run custom code to forward appointments in another person's calendar to me automatically when they are added to her outlook calendar.  I already have the code but I need it to run when a particular form closes.  If I choose the on close property of the form, it wants to create it's own event procedure.  I can use a macro and use the runcode but then it wants the name of a function.  So I need an example of that custom function.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you cannot use the close event like so:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
   MyCustomSub
End Sub
```